# JavaMail - Mask "from" address

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have a piece of software I am developing that includes user accounts and login/passwords. For password storage/protection, I am using an asymmetric salt+hash system, and thus, if a user forgets their password, I would like the software to send a password reset link to the user's email address.

My question is this: is it possible to send this email from an address that does not actually exist (like do-not-reply@myproject.com)? Alternatively, is there a way to send it from a real email address but to mask the "from" address and make it appear to the recipient as do-not-reply@myproject.com even if it truly came from myemail@gmail.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can send the e-mail to appear to come from any address.  It is important to recognize that there are two 'from' addresses - the envelope sender is often not displayed to the recipient but indicates the server that is sending the message.  The 'from' address is different and is specified in the message headers.  As this is what what the recipient sees, it sounds like you simply need to customize your 'from' address header in the message.

Note: Some users will have e-mail servers that require proof that your server is authorized to send e-mail from the domain in the 'from' header.  You can do this with an SPF record on the mydomain.com DNS zone file.